# hibernate 4 log4j view query params

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, log4j

I have an web app hosted on glassfish 4 built with hibernate (JPA) and JSF and I want to view the query params.
Some time ago I could see these parameters but I guess that when I switched from hibernate 3.x to 4.x the log functionality disappeared.
So I have in my persistence.xml:

```
<property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
<property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
```

and in my log4j.properties:

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.jdbc=trace
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type= trace
```

The fact is that I can see the queries but instead of params I see question marks.
I have read something about the fact that hibernate4 uses jboss logging and i have added this :

```
-Dorg.jboss.logging.provider=log4j
```

to my jvm parameters in glassfish but still no luck.
Any ideas ?

Comment: Do you have slf4j-log4j12.jar in your jars?

Comment: I have tried with and without  slf4j-log4j12.jar in my maven pom but the result is the same.

Comment: Hibernate 4 uses JBoss logging instead of slf4j. See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/topical/html/logging/Logging.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [setting up your application](http://vladmihalcea.com/the-minimal-configuration-for-testing-hibernate/) to you [datasource-proxy](https://github.com/ttddyy/datasource-proxy/) in front of your actual DataSource.

The datasource-proxy can intercept all queries and log parameters nicely. I've been using this logging method in all examples of my [on-line Hibernate training material](http://vladmihalcea.com/tutorials/hibernate/), and you can check the configuration on [GitHub](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-master-class/blob/master/core/src/test/java/com/vladmihalcea/hibernate/masterclass/laboratory/util/AbstractTest.java) as well.

```
Query:{[
select
    product0_.id as id1_18_1_,
    product0_.code as code2_18_1_,
    product0_.company_id as company_6_18_1_,
    product0_.importer_id as importer7_18_1_,
    product0_.name as name3_18_1_,
    product0_.quantity as quantity4_18_1_,
    product0_.version as version5_18_1_,
    company1_.id as id1_6_0_,
    company1_.name as name2_6_0_
from Product product0_
inner join Company company1_ on product0_.company_id=company1_.id
where product0_.id=?][1]
```

Between square brackets you are going to find the PreparedStatament parameters. It even works when calling procedures and functions.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, i will fallback to this if i cannot manage to solve it in a "more classic" way.

Comment: Try adding a break point in LoggerManager where Log4j config is loaded. This way you can be sure that your config gets loaded and not some other log4j.xml file from some other jar.

Comment: the loaded file is the correct one as if i change something there it is reflected to the logger behavior. I guess that as a last resort i will use some proxy datasource.

Comment: I think you should also fill a bug in Hibernate and provide a test case to replicate it.

Answer (score 1):

Glassfish admin console -> Configurations -> Server-config -> Logger Settings -> Log levels -> Add Logger -> org.hibernate.type : FINEST

[image: Glassfish logger settings]

source : https://cumacakmak.wordpress.com/2015/01/18/glassfish-hibernate-binding-parameters-easy-way/